# .tmx file saved in uncompressed fromat to comressed format

Tags: libgdx, tile

I have created .tmx file from tile editor.
it is saved in uncomressed format.
but now i wnat it in zlib compressed format.

i used Edit > Preferences but after changing it to comressed format , it is not reflecting any changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember experiencing this as well.
I think it's a bug. Try saving the file with a different name and close and reopen the TilEd again. After that the settings should apply and you will save it with the correct compression.

http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsTileMaps says that certain libgdx backends (GWT) do not support all compressions. So be careful with that.

Comment: thanks @Noon , I have tried on other computer(partners computer) and it worked...
might be this is issue of the software that you have mentioned..